# OOP and DB access

Tags: database, class, oop

I used to have a single BLL class for each DataTable in my DAL.
Trying to follow OOP principles I divided each class to two classes as following:

- class Item - represents a single item/row.
  includes:

  1. fields and properties according to the table's fields.
  2. constructors - they don't access the DB
  3. static Get method - returns a single Item from DB.
  4. Delete method - deletes an Item from DB.
  5. Update method - updates an Item in DB.
- class Items - represents a sorted list of objects of class Item. key is the item's ID. includes:

  1. field items_list of type SortedList
  2. constructors - access the DB to fill items_list
  3. GetList method - returns items_list

My questions:
1. As you can see, the Item class doesn't include any insert method, because I can't decide in which one of the classes it should be.
2. Is it ok to have a Get method in Items that will return an Item by its ID.
3. Is it ok to have Update and Delete methods in the Items class that will retrieve an Item from the items_list and then call the corresponding methods of Item.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You would benefit from reading about [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) and [repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). Once you pick a language you can use specific technologies for that, for example in C# there is NHibernate, Entity Framework, generic repository pattern are quite popular.

> As you can see, the Item class doesn't include any insert method, because I can't decide in which one of the classes it should be.

Domain class shall not include any data access layer stuff. Keep it separate as these are different responsibilities. Have a look at the [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) and [Domain Driven Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design).

> Is it ok to have a Get method in Items that will return an Item by its ID.

No, not okay. Remove *any* data access members from the domain model classes.

> Is it ok to have Update and Delete methods in the Items class that will retrieve an Item from the items_list and then call the corresponding methods of Item.

No, same reason as for the other ones.

In short, one class - one responsibility. Separate model from database interaction. Use separate generic classes to interact with the database, use ORMs. Have a look at couple of tutorials about that patterns and technologies.

Comment: By DB access I meant calling a method from DAL, not an actual connection to DB. All the class methods (get, update, delete, insert) only use the corresponding methods from DAL.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunaetely the answer is 'NO' to the three question. I think that as oleksii explained in his answer, you are mixing different responsibilities in the same classes.
A class should have only one responsibility[(Single Responsibility Principle)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

- `Item` should represent the data of one record so it should be limited to its properties.
- `Items` should represent a recordset, a collection of Item (...that you might iterate). What you should get after a query, thus.

There should be at least a third class, call it DAO (Data Acess Object) or manager in charge of performing the DB operations such as `Get`, `GetList`, `Update`, `Delete` and `Insert`.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to explain. I HAVE a DAL that contains DataTables and DataTableAdapters. Item and Items are classes in the BLL that use the DB operations from DAL.

Comment: @YevgeniGrinberg The fact the you access database directly or not doesn't matter. What I say doesn't depend on the tier. The thing is that you are mixing responsibilities. Here I see classes representing the information itself and handling it. You should separate it in order to have classes representing the information and classes performing operations on it.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of it. Why have one class with just properties and no functions and another class with just functions and no properties? Isn't the class supposed to represent an object and all the operations regarding it?